# Loading a DLL file either at runtime or by adding references

Tags: vb.net, dll

I just want to get this right. Which is better exactly when loading a bunch of dll in VB.NET, is it by adding a reference or loading it dynamically using code at runtime, I mean which makes the program more responsive and not lag or just like the advantages and disadvantages of each would be highly appreciated. Because am thinking of loading all the required libraries during the splash screen but am not so sure on which is a great idea. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean "loading at runtime"?  Via reflection?  The compiler will not load all your DLL references at startup, it will compile them "just in time" when needed.  From a design standpoint, adding references is much simpler.

Comment: yea via reflection, loading them into the app domain, and but won't the program lag at startup due to too many referenced dll? @roryap

Comment: what is `a bunch` for you? .NET in the combination with modern hardware is quite fast when it comes to loading of references. If you talk about hundred of dlls it could take some time. But like @roryap said, the assemblies are typically loaded when they are needed unless you tell .NET otherwise.

Comment: I am talking about something like a hundred or close to that, and plus i don't wanna assume that every system that my program will be run to will be modern that's why I was asking which is faster or will add responsiveness to the system @AlexB.